# Javascript and HTML - Variable Doesn't Show Up

Tags: javascript, html, mixpanel

I have the following code snippet in HTML:

```
 <form class="navbar-search pull-right search-query" value = "" action="/search/?q=" style="line-height:25px;">
    <input type="text" id="navbarsearch" class="search-query span2" style="border-radius:14px 14px 14px 14px;" name = "q" placeholder="Search">
      <i class="icon-search icon-white" onclick="document.forms.search.submit();"></i>
         &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
 </form>
```

I'm trying to pass this variable to Javascript as follows, but the query variable is not being passed properly for some reason I don't think....

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#navbarsearch").click(function() {
        // This sends us an event every time a user clicks the button
        mixpanel.track('SearchQuery', {'query': document.getElementById('navbarsearch').value, 'url' : window.location.pathname});
    });
</script>
```

The action is showing up in MixPanel, but the query variable is not. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to put it inside the document.ready:

```
$(function() {   //  <--- there.
    $("#navbarsearch").click(function() {
    mixpanel.track(
        'SearchQuery',
        {
            'query': $(this).val(),   
            'url' : window.location.pathname
        }
    );
});
});
```

Comment: I tried this, it's detecting the event, and tracking the URL,  but not the query....

Comment: I've edited the answer. You need to put it inside the document.ready.

Comment: Hmm now it's not event detecting the event that way. Could it be conflicting with other JAvascript on the page?

Answer (score 0):

The click event is set off when a user clicks with their mouse. I think you want to listen to keystrokes?

Try:

```
$("#navbarsearch").keydown(function() {
    mixpanel.track('SearchQuery', {
         'query': document.getElementById('navbarsearch').value,
         'url' : window.location.pathname
    });
});
```